# How to turn On/OFF closed captions in HLS Streaming URL in Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using **Exoplayer Version 2.0.4** to play **HLS Streams**(.m3u8). My HLS streams contains the closed captions with it. How can i control the closed captions with exoplayer? Is it feasible to hide/show the subtitle when required and change the placement of the subtitle layout if required?

Comment: Hi Ram, were you able to display the subtitles successfully? If so can you share your code to add subtitles with version 2 of Exoplayer? Thanks

Comment: In Exoplayer, i was able to customise closed captions by playing with the SimpleExoplayer View class in github project. You can able to hide/show, change title text font, color, placements ...

Comment: @RamJay were you able to show/hide subtitles? I also have managed to show the subtitles in Exoplayer but now want to turn them ON/OFF. How do you do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to control caption selection in ExoPlayer 2 using a `DefaultTrackSelector`. The code below was modified based on the ExoPlayer 2 Demo's [`TrackSelectionHelper`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/TrackSelectionHelper.java) class, which should be referenced for more implementation details.

To turn captions off, you need to disable the renderer for the text tracks and clear the selection overrides.

```
trackSelector.setRendererDisabled(TRACK_TEXT, true);
trackSelector.clearSelectionOverrides();
```

`TRACK_TEXT` is a local static variable I created representing the index of the text tracks (2), in relation to video/audio tracks. I believe that SelectionOverrides are just programmatically specified track selections.

To enable the tracks again, you need to enable the renderer for text tracks, and then set up a new `SelectionOverride` for your desired text track. Before you can do this, you need to get the `TrackGroupArray` of the currently mapped text tracks from your `DefaultTrackSelector`.

```
MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo = trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo();
TrackGroupArray textGroups = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(TRACK_TEXT); // list of captions
int groupIndex = 1; // index of desired caption track within the textGroups array

trackSelector.setRendererDisabled(TRACK_TEXT, false);
MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride override = 
    new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(fixedFactory, groupIndex, 0);
trackSelector.setSelectionOverride(TRACK_TEXT, textGroups, override);
```

For more implementation details (e.g., initializing the trackSelector and fixedFactory), check out the [ExoPlayer 2 Demo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main).

You can use a `SubtitleView` to position the captions within your layout. Your class will need to implement `TextRenderer.Output` and override the `onCues()` method.

```
@Override
public void onCues(List<Cue> cues) {
    if (subtitleView != null) {
        subtitleView.onCues(cues);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you pass the subtitle Uri/link to this code?

Comment: @SamRamezanli See here for how to create a media source and prepare the player: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#preparing-the-player
We are using HLS so the text and video tracks are all included in one manifest/url. Further implementation details were based on the [demo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo)

Comment: Thanks @Taylor but I'm using DASH and I need to link the captions to the video. I'm currently using the same solution in the link you shared, however, this method doesn't allow us to enable and disable captions unless we release and re-initiate the player.

Comment: I have the same problem which is mentioned by @Sam Ramezanli and  I have a scenario like while switching to next clip close caption of the previous video will show in the current clip. may I know how to control this kind of issue.

Comment: There is no `TrackSelectionHelper` class in the demo app now and the methods used in your code are not present anymore.

Comment: @khateeb Most of the methods referenced are on the DefaultTrackSelector class, so those should still be a part of the library. However, you're right, it does look like the TrackSelectionHelper file was swapped out for a different approach in this commit: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/commit/6ac252843ec990ff32acb30429f2173ea44b73c9

Comment: for me this answer is not working ..i am using exoplayer version 2.7.1

Comment: How would you remove or hide a particular closed caption/subtitle from the track groups, say a forced subtitle?

Answer (score 12):

In my application I initialize the `trackselecktor` as follow

**To turn off close captions from video track**

```
trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    trackSelector.setParameters(new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder()
            .setRendererDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO, true)
            .build()
    );
```

**To turn on close captions from video track**

```
trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    trackSelector.setParameters(new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder()
            .setRendererDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO, false)
            .build()
    );
```

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: you may need to set preferred language.

Answer (score 3):

After updating the ExoPlayer library to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.5'
```

I found that the `MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride` method does not exist anymore.

I was unable to find a working alternative, as just replacing with `DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride` didn't work for me, and subtitles were not playing in my case for video.

```
MediaSource mediaSource =  new HlsMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
```

Final set of lines which worked for me:

```
TrackGroupArray trackGroups = trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo().getTrackGroups(newSubtitle.renderIndex);

DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = trackSelector.buildUponParameters();

DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride sOverride = new DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(newSubtitle.groupIndex, newSubtitle.indexWithinGroup);

boolean isDisabled = trackSelector.getParameters().getRendererDisabled(newSubtitle.renderIndex);

paramsBuilder.setRendererDisabled(newSubtitle.renderIndex, isDisabled);

if (sOverride != null) {
    paramsBuilder.setSelectionOverride(newSubtitle.renderIndex, trackGroups, sOverride);
} else {
    paramsBuilder.clearSelectionOverrides(newSubtitle.renderIndex);
}

trackSelector.setParameters(paramsBuilder);
```

Old code was:

```
TrackGroupArray trackGroups = trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo().getTrackGroups(newSubtitle.renderIndex);

MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride sOverride = new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(
    new FixedTrackSelection.Factory(), 
    newSubtitle.groupIndex, 
    newSubtitle.indexWithinGroup
);

trackSelector.setSelectionOverride(newSubtitle.renderIndex, trackGroups, sOverride);
trackSelector.setRendererDisabled(newSubtitle.renderIndex, false);
```

To close subtitles:

```java
DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = trackSelector.buildUponParameters();

paramsBuilder.setRendererDisabled(playingSubtitle.renderIndex, true);

trackSelector.setParameters(paramsBuilder);
```

Comment: Where are you getting `newSubtitle` from?

Comment: Your Answer is very good but newSubtitle is missleading. Didnt downvote though..

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend don't use the constant `TRACK_TEXT` or `C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT` as this:

```
trackSelector.setRendererDisabled(TRACK_TEXT, true);
trackSelector.clearSelectionOverrides();
```

because it could vary depends on the asset which you are using, you can ensure that you are disabling the correct renderer with the following code (Kotlin version):

```
  private fun disableSubtitles(){
    (0 until (trackSelector.currentMappedTrackInfo?.rendererCount ?: 0)).filter {position ->
      player.getRendererType(position) == C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT
    }.map {position ->
      trackSelector.parameters = trackSelector.buildUponParameters()
          .setRendererDisabled(position,true)
          .clearSelectionOverrides(position)
          .build()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To disable a track, let's say a Subtitle(Text) track, you need to use **DefaultTrackSelector** that you've passed earlier to `ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance`, to disable a track you need its **rendererIndex**. There are actually two confusing(at least for me!) terms in selecting the tracks in **ExoPlayer**, one is **TrackType** and the other one is **RendererIndex**. Basically there are some TrackTypes which can be accessed in **com.google.android.exoplayer2.C** class and the main ones are **TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO**, **TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO** and **TRACK_TYPE_TEXT**. but **rendererIndex** on the other hand could be any number starting from 0 (I guess). So to disable a track you need to find it's rendererIndex first. then use the code below to disable the track:

```
trackSelector
            ?.buildUponParameters()
            ?.setRendererDisabled(rendererIndex, true)
            ?.let {
                trackSelector?.setParameters(it)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Xamarin.Android:

```
[Obsolete]
private DefaultTrackSelector CreateTrackSelector()
{
    var bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    var videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    var trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    var trackParameter = new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder()
         // disables closed caption / subtitle
        .SetDisabledTextTrackSelectionFlags(C.TrackTypeText)
        .Build();
    trackSelector.SetParameters(trackParameter);
    return trackSelector;
}
```